# Input validation for empty fields and integer values

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtable, text-files

I'm trying to save data in `Students.txt` (in one `JFrame`) and then open it in a `JTable` (according to percentage - high to low) in a different frame.

This is the code I have for writing the text file (which it does Ok)
the only thing I still want to add is, that it shows an error message if either one of the txt inputs is empty or if `txtInputMark` is not an integer value.

```
    package hpxs200.pkg1;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;
    import java.io.File;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;

   public class frmRegistration extends javax.swing.JFrame {
   String strInput1;
    String strInput2;
    String strInput3;
    Integer intInput1;
   File Textfile = new File("Student.txt");

   private void btnSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
     strInput1 = txtInputFName.getText();
    strInput2 = txtInputLName.getText();
    strInput3 = txtInputMark.getText();
      try
      {
          Textfile.createNewFile();
          lblOutput1.setText("Student information has been saved");
      }
      catch (Exception Ex)
      {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,Ex);
      }

     try 
     {
         String strfilename = "Student.txt";
         FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(strfilename, true);
         fw.write(strInput1 + ";");
         fw.write(strInput2 + ";");
         fw.write(strInput3 + "\n");
         fw.close();
     }
     catch (IOException | NumberFormatException Ex)
     {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, Ex);
     }
}                                       

private void txtInputMarkActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                            

private void btnClearActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    txtInputFName.setText("");
    txtInputLName.setText("");
    txtInputMark.setText("");'''
```

**This is all I have for the retrieving of the data, I can't figure out what to do.**

I would like the data from the text file to be displayed in a table, from the highest mark to lowest mark, keep in mind the data file was created in another frame.

```
private void btnDisplayStudentInfoActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    String strInput4;
    BufferedReader brReader = null;
    InputStreamReader isReader = null;
   try{
        try (FileInputStream fisFin = new FileInputStream("Students.txt"); 
           InputStreamReader isrReader = new InputStreamReader(fisFin))
        {
            brReader = newBufferedReader(isrReader);
            while((strInput4 = brReader.readLine()) !=null)
            {
                lblOutput.setText("content has been read");
            }
            brReader.close();
        }
   }
   catch (Exception Ex)
   {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Ex);
   }
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code. 3) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 4) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: 5) The text file is variously named `Student.txt`, `Students.txt` & `student.txt`. It appears multiple times in the code. Best define is as a `public static final STUDENT_TEXT_FILENAME` and always use that attribute. 6) While on the subject of nomenclature.. Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.